# Classic asp - 64 bit MDAC reference problem

Tags: asp-classic

I got an very basic test.asp page that needs to run on a 64-bit server

first i tried

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library" UUID="{00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4}" VERSION="2.5"-->
<% 
.... more code
```

does not work (even though i found the reference in COM)
the i try

```
<!--METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" NAME="Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library" UUID="{2A75196C-D9EB-4129-B803-931327F72D5C}" VERSION="2.8"-->
<% 
... more code
```

this works ,, but why can't i reference the 2.5 version when the library exist on the server?

Comment: If i look under reference in Regedit. Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 library references to file C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado25.tlp 
And 
Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 library references to file C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\System\ado\msado15.dll Im wondering if the answer lies in the limitation in 64 bit on refering to ".tlp" vs ".dll"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Josip is nearly correct MDAC 2.5 is only 32 bit (2.8 has a 64 bit flavour).  By default on 64 bit server your application pool will run using 64 bit processes.  It will be looking in the 64 bit version of the system hive for the 2.5 type library reference but won't find it (its only in the 32 bit version).

If you edit your application pool settings so that it runs as 32 bit you should find the 2.5 reference will work.

Comment: thx for the answer, i believe you are right. One thing still remain unanswered. The msado25.tlp type library resides in both C:\Program Files\Common Files\System\ado and C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\System\ado why does the reference only work with 2.8? Thx for your time, very appreciated

Comment: I would guess its there for completeness, they will be identical.  The only difference is that 2.5 isn't registered in the 64 bit hive.

Comment: Is there a reason to not just use 2.8?

Answer (score 0):

MDAC is available only on 32-bit.

You must change your application to target x86 (by default it targets AnyCPU). It will still run on x64 but with smaller memory space.

Comment: thx for helping out. 

Maybe im missing something .. but this is a classic ASP page, within a asp.net app. So basically i do have to do any compilation. Why then does the platform setting affect the outcome? 

Anyways why does the reference to 2.8 work then?

Comment: @Josip: If you believe the answer is incorrect you should delete it.